# Calculation of expiry date for new insertion

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
insert into recharge (user_id, package_id, recharge_date, expiry_date)
values ('datta_vcc','mb02','2013-06-06',
           new.recharge_date+((select validity from internet_package where
           internet_package.package_id=new.package_id)*24*60*60));
```

I want to calculate the expiry date from validity, which is available in internet_package table. But this insert query is throwing error saying: unknown column 'new.recharge_date' in 'field list'. How do i solve it?

Comment: are user_id,recharge_date also present in internet_package table?Why are you hardcoding the values of them?

Comment: is this inside a trigger?

Comment: @Algorithmist, no, internet_package only contains package details, there is no user information.

Comment: @skv, no its a plain insert query

Comment: @Algorithmist, I am testing the queries now. All the values will be fetched from a from in the front end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into recharge (user_id, package_id, recharge_date, expiry_date)
select 'datta_vcc','mb02','2013-05-06',date_add('2013-05-06', INTERVAL validity day)
from internet_package
where internet_package.package_id = 'mb02';
```

For now this seems to work. The hard-coded values will be fetched from a form in the front end. Can this query be optimized further?